# Game freezes upon load from home screen

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

After installing the heists update, when I shut off my Xbox One and turn it back on, start GTA V from the home screen, and it loads, I cannot move around. But I can access the pause menu and when I look around, it shows the minimap moving directions.

Is there a workaround for this issue, or will I have to keep loading the game manually from the pause menu?

Comment: The heists update is very buggy... especially on next generation versions. I would wait for the next update.